# Как программировать на C# в Unreal Engine?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, mono, unreal-engine-4

На оффициальном сайте  http://mono-ue.github.io/download.html ничего нету про установку моно для Unreal Engine.

Говорится что разработка неактивна.

This Project is not Actively Developed.

Hello,

As you guys have noticed, the experience to setup Mono with Unreal Engine
is not very pleasant.   It involves compiling code from source, it involves
a specific version of Unreal and has a very long and tedious installation
process.

The Unreal EULA is hostile to third party vendors and prevents us from
creating the kind of integrated experience that we would like to have.

Based on the above, we do not anticipate that we will continue to develop
the bindings of Mono for Unreal Engine at this point.

**Но можно как-то попробовать уже то что создано? Мне не удалось найти как mono устанавливать в Unreal Engine?**

Comment: Mono установите

Comment: а подробней? Обычную версию ?  Их как интегрировать?

Comment: Лень на соседнюю ссылку нажать, вопрос в топку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Установка Mono для Unreal Engine

**Создание Unreal Engine с плагинами Mono.**

Чтобы установить Mono для Unreal Engine, вам нужно будет создать Unreal Editor из исходного кода, а затем добавить расширение Mono, которое позволит использовать C# с Unreal Engine.

Текущая надстройка была протестирована с версией 4.4. На этой странице описывается, как настроить Unreal Engine, чтобы разрешить разработку C # с помощью Mono и как настроить ваши IDE MonoDevelop или XamarinStudio для написания кода C #.

**Сборка Unreal Engine из исходников**

1. Во-первых, клонируйте репозиторий Unreal Engine с помощью Git. Это
   можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine).

> Вам нужно связать свою учетную запись Unreal с учетной записью github.
>   Войдите в свою учетную запись на главной странице UE, затем нажмите
>   «ACCOUNT» там UPDATE GITHUB ACCOUNT: поле, ваше имя пользователя gihub
>   и нажмите «СОХРАНИТЬ ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ», а затем, возможно, через некоторое
>   время unrealbot в github предоставит вам доступ к репозиториям UE и UT

---

> Не стоит забывать, что ваша учетная запись должна быть активной в этот
>   момент, чтобы иметь возможность получить доступ к репо на github.
>
> Убедитесь, что у вас активная учетная запись
>   (https://www.unrealengine.com/dashboard)
>
> Создайте учетную запись GitHub (https://github.com)
>
> На сайте UnrealEngine свяжите свою учетную запись github с настройками
>   пользователя (https://www.unrealengine.com/settings)
>
> Перейдите в https://github.com/EpicGames.
>
> Загрузите необходимый код (либо Unreal Engine, либо Unreal Tournament)

2. Проверьте ветку 4.4. Вы можете сделать это,
   запустив: 
   Git checkout 4.4

   Вы также можете использовать одно из
   настольных приложений git, если хотите.
3. Загрузите необходимые
   зависимости 4.4. Есть два ZIP-файла: [здесь](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/releases/download/4.4.3-release/Required_1of2.zip) и [здесь](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/releases/download/4.4.3-release/Required_2of2.zip)
4. Распакуйте эти
   зависимости в каталог, к которому клонировали репозиторий
   UrealEngine. Будьте осторожны, чтобы убедиться, что папки объединены
   вместе, а не перезаписаны (на Mac это можно сделать с помощью
   опции-> перетаскивания папки в каталог UnrealEngine и нажатия «Keep
   Newer» при появлении запроса).

**Windows**

1. Для сборки исходного кода на Windows, вам потребуется Visual Studio установлена 2013. Вы можете использовать бесплатную версию, если Вы не владеете ею, в Visual Studio 2013 сообщество.
2. Установить время выполнения июнь 2010, совместимая с DirectX. Это может быть найдено [здесь](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109).
3. В папку нами (каталог клонирован РЕПО в), запустить `GenerateProjectFiles.bat` Это должно быстро работать.
4. Теперь вы можете открыть решение в Visual Studio, который вы только что создали (следует назвать UE4.sln).
5. После установки Visual Studio имеет открыт, установить конфигурацию решения для редактор развития и установить платформу х64. Постройте проект, выбрав команду создать из выпадающего меню. Это может занять некоторое время (до 40 минут в зависимости от вашей системы), так что идти вперед и сделаем перерыв. Выпить кофе или еще что-то.
6. Затем вы можете запустить редактор из Visual Studio путем установки проекта UE4, как ваш стартап-проект и нажав на зеленый треугольник на панели инструментов (или клавишу F5).
7. Наконец, Вы можете настроить ваш оболочкой Windows, так что вы можете взаимодействовать .uproject файлов. Найти файл с названием `UnrealVersionSelector-Win64-Shippping.exe` в `UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Win64/_` папку и запустить его. Теперь вы сможете дважды щелкнуть .uproject файлы для загрузки проекта, или щелкните правой кнопкой мыши, чтобы быстро обновить визуальную студию файлов.

Добавление моно для нереального двигателя
После того, как Вы успешно построили Нереальный Двигатель 4.4 из источника, Вы можете добавить Моно для Нереальных плагинов Двигателя. Вот то, как сделать это:

**Добавление Mono для Unreal Engine**

После того, как вы успешно создали Unreal Engine 4.4 из исходного кода, вы можете добавить плагины Mono для Unreal Engine. Вот как это сделать:

Загрузите zip-файл Mono для Unreal Engine с нашей страницы загрузки (если вы еще этого не сделали). Файл следует называть XamarinUE4.zip.
Извлеките zip-файл в исходный каталог UnrealEngine, снова убедившись, что папки объединены, а не перезаписаны, так же, как и раньше.
Затем вы можете запускать команды терминала в каталоге UnrealEngine (если вы используете настольное приложение, вы можете запустить окно терминала / консоли из приложения с выбранным репозитором UnrealEngine):

```
git checkout 4.4
git checkout -b 4.4-xamarin
git am Engine/Plugins/XamarinUE4/Patches/*
```

Это должно создать новую ветвь git под названием «4.4-xamarin» с применяемыми и совершенными патчами Mono for Unreal Engine.
Теперь вы можете перестроить Unreal Editor так же, как и раньше; Плагины Mono для Unreal Engine и привязывающие сборки будут включены автоматически.

http://mono-ue.github.io/installation.html

Comment: Забавно конечно, что ссылка на репо битая